# How to concatenate the Column A values to Column B Using Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

Hi i tried to concatenate the values of Column A to Column B with text "Color-" But Column A contains the multiple color values. i want Each Color value should concatenate with the Value "Color-" in the Column B. I tried this Formula  =CONCATENATE("Color-",A2) But its not Work In my case. Please see the Image For Your Reference, Can Anybody Help on this.
 [image]

Answer (score 1):

If you were wanting to use VBA, you can create a function which you can then use within the worksheet.

```
Public Function addString(ByVal list As String, ByVal prefix As String) As String

    Dim i As Long
    Dim splitWords() As String
    Dim joinedWords As String

    splitWords = Split(list, ",")

    For i = LBound(splitWords) To UBound(splitWords)

        If i < UBound(splitWords) Then
            joinedWords = joinedWords & prefix & "-" & splitWords(i) & ","
        Else
            joinedWords = joinedWords & prefix & "-" & splitWords(i)
        End If

    Next i

    addString = joinedWords
End Function
```

You can then type `=addString()` in the worksheet. The function will take 2 arguments - the list of colours which are delimited by a comma, and the string which you wish to prefix to each colour in the list.

**Example:** `=addString($A$1,A2)`

You can then drag this function down the column. There's probably a way to do this using Array formulas; personally I prefer creating custom functions.

Comment: Hi @ituner, thanks  for Your Reply, I tried this code but it ll not concatenate on all the Color value. It ll concatenate only to last color like this   Beige,Blue-------------->Beige,Blue,-COLOR

Comment: You are putting the ranges into the function the wrong way around :). You should first enter the range containing the list, then the range which contains the word you want to prefix to each list item.